# compiling Opensips on Clion: missing tap.h, which library is missing?

Tags: cmake, clion, opensips

I am trying to compile Opensips on Clion as I want to debug and step through the code. I have tried adding environment variables through following lines in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-funroll-loops -Wcast-align -Wall -minline-all-stringops -falign-loops -ftree-vectorize -mtune=nocona -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wredundant-decls" )

add_definitions(-DPKG_MALLOC -DSHM_MMAP -DUSE_MCAST -DDISABLE_NAGLE -DSTATISTICS -DHAVE_RESOLV_RES -DF_MALLOC -DF_MALLOC_OPTIMIZATIONS -DNAME='"opensips"' -DVERSION='"2.4.2"' -DARCH='"x86_64"' -DOS='"linux"' -DCOMPILER='"gcc 4.8.5"' -D__CPU_x86_64 -D__OS_linux -D__SMP_yes -DCFG_DIR='"/usr/local//etc/opensips/"' -DVERSIONTYPE='"git"' -DTHISREVISION='"c035556"' -DFAST_LOCK -DADAPTIVE_WAIT -DADAPTIVE_WAIT_LOOPS=1024 -DHAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME2 -DHAVE_UNION_SEMUN -DHAVE_SCHED_YIELD -DHAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL -DHAVE_MSGHDR_MSG_CONTROL -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_TIMEGM -DHAVE_EPOLL -DHAVE_SIGIO_RT -DHAVE_SELECT)
```

===========================================================

I get following errors and I am not sure which package is missing:

-- Build files have been written to: /root/opensips-2.4/cmake-build-debug
[ 0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/opensips_2_4.dir/cachedb/test/test_backends.c.o
[ 0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/opensips_2_4.dir/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c.o
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/test/test_backends.c:21:17: fatal error: tap.h: No such file or directory

## include

^
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opensips_2_4.dir/cachedb/test/test_backends.c.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
MODULE_VERSION,
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘exports.version’) [enabled by default]
In file included from /root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/../../sr_module.h:52:0,
from /root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:32:
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/../../version.h:26:37: error: expected ‘}’ before string constant

## define OPENSIPS_FULL_VERSION NAME " " VERSION " (" ARCH "/" OS ")"

^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/../../sr_module.h:102:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘OPENSIPS_FULL_VERSION’
OPENSIPS_FULL_VERSION, 
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_VERSION’
MODULE_VERSION,
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:75:2: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:89:1: warning: missing initializer for field ‘compile_flags’ of ‘struct module_exports’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
};
^
In file included from /root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:32:0:
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/../../sr_module.h:175:8: note: ‘compile_flags’ declared here
char compile_flags; /!< compile flags used on the module */
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:95:12: warning: ‘mod_init’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static int mod_init(void)
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:137:12: warning: ‘child_init’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static int child_init(int rank)
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:154:13: warning: ‘destroy’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static void destroy(void)
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:59:21: warning: ‘cmds’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
static cmd_export_t cmds[]=
^
/root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c:65:23: warning: ‘params’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
static param_export_t params[]={
^
gmake[2]:*  [CMakeFiles/opensips_2_4.dir/cachedb/example/example_cachedb.c.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: * [CMakeFiles/opensips_2_4.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tap.h` error is due to the fact that you have enabled unit-testing support in your build, via the `-DUNIT_TESTS` flag in `Makefile.conf`.  If you still want to go down this route and run the cachedb-related unit tests for MongoDB/Cassandra:

- download libtap, from [here](https://github.com/zorgnax/libtap)
- `make` and `sudo make install`

Comment: #DEFS+= -DUNIT_TESTS is commented out and I think it shouldn't be compiling? Let me install libtap and see if that helps.

One more question, the second error I am getting in the above code, any idea how to fix it, as I have not changed anything in the code yet:
32: /root/opensips-2.4/cachedb/example/../../version.h:26:37: error: expected ‘}’ before string constant

Comment: You are not using the project's Makefile code, so you are on your own. 
 Please do as Răzvan told you in issue #1513. https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips/issues/1513.

Comment: I am trying to do the same. I want to step through the code but unable to compile it. I have not added any file or changed anything in Makefile. I tried to add environment variables as suggested but seems like i am doing it the wrong way. 
I did try adding enviornment variable from Clion IDE but that didn't work then I tried it from CMakeLists with CMAKE_C_FLAG and add_definition but niether of them worked :(

Comment: /root/opensips-2.4/db/example/dbexample.c:42:2: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘enum module_type’ using type ‘char **’
  },
  ^

Comment: The environment variables issue is fixed, now this error is occurring when trying to compile

Comment: that is just dummy code, it doesn't even compile.  `rm -fr` that file as well as any other "example" files you find.